# как определить пятиминутные отрезки времени

Tags: r

Пытаюсь сделать атоматический запуск скрипта R
Мне нужно запускать скрип каждую новую пятиминутку
сделал вот так

```
    while (TRUE) {

   Sys.sleep(300)

      print(Sys.time())

-------------
Основной код
-------------
}
```

но из за того что основной код выполняется довольно долго, получается неприемлемо сильное смещение по времени

```
[1] "2018-07-23 09:37:02 CEST"
[1] "2018-07-23 09:42:37 CEST"
[1] "2018-07-23 09:48:48 CEST"
[1] "2018-07-23 09:55:05 CEST"
```

Я думаю сделать так : в цикле  while постоянно проверять время  Sys.time() и когда наступает начало новой пятиминутки   9:45:01 далее 9:50:01 итд. запускать скрипт

Но как должен выглядеть код по определению той самой пятиминутки? кто знает?
Или есть альтернативные способы?
Зарание спасибо за ответ

Comment: Получите время выполнения "основного кода", лучше в секундах. 5*60 = 300, и сделайте sleep на 300-время_сек (проверив что время_сек < 300)

Comment: Дело в том что код всегда выполняется за разное кол. времени , но точно меньше чем за 5 мин, для меня самый лучший способ реализации это запуск на каждой новой пятиминутке  типа так: 9:45:01 далее 9:50:01 итд.

Comment: Я вашу мысль понял... можно сделать типа `while ( (min % 5) != 0 ) sleep(1);`

Comment: Простите, а можете написать код полностью как он должен быть, я просто программист не очень, а то что вы написали не запускается ((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Более рационально воспользоваться планировщиком задач. Данный функционал для Windows реализован в пакете `taskscheduleR`.

```
library(taskscheduleR)
script_path <- file.path("bin", "script.R")
# Создаём задание
taskscheduler_create(taskname = "myfancyscript_5min", rscript = script_path, schedule = "MINUTE", modifier = 5)
# Получаем список заданий
tasks <- taskscheduler_ls()
str(tasks)
# Удаляем задание
# taskscheduler_delete(taskname = "myfancyscript")
```

Для Linux есть пакет с похожим функционалом - `cronR`.